# Libgdx HTML project not compiling (No source code is available...)

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, libgdx

for the first time I'm trying to use the HTML version of a libgdx project and I'm having trouble compiling the project. The compileGwt task fails with this:

```
[ERROR] Line 21: No source code is available for type de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook.core.GDXFacebook; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[ERROR] Line 30: No source code is available for type io.netty.channel. socket.SocketChannel; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

There's loads more of the same kind of error for various classes. My question is: is it possible to have Netty and the gdx-facebook extension working in the HTML version of the project? If so, how can this be done? Please note, I know nothing about GWT besides the layman's "it converts java to javascript code". For more information, please ask.
Thanks

EDIT: Attaching .iml file from html project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id=":html" external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/.." external.system.id="GRADLE" external.system.module.group="portablefun" external.system.module.version="1.1" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android-gradle" name="Android-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="GRADLE_PROJECT_PATH" value=":html" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
    <facet type="java-gradle" name="Java-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="BUILD_FOLDER_PATH" value="$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
        <option name="BUILDABLE" value="true" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_6" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/main" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/test" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.gradle" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="module" module-name="core" exported="" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="gdx-backend-gwt-1.9.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="gdx-backend-gwt-1.9.3-sources" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="gdx-1.9.3-sources" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="gdx-1.9.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="gdx-box2d-1.9.3-sources" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="gdx-box2d-gwt-1.9.3-sources" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="json-20160212" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="gwt-user-2.6.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="gdx-box2d-1.9.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="validation-api-1.0.0.GA" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="RUNTIME" name="gwt-servlet-2.6.0" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

GWT compiles Java to Javascript, but only Java classes that have been emulated or written using GWT own classes. I think you need to inherit this in your module descriptor:

```
<inherits name = "src.de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook.GdxFacebookCore">
```

Comment: Here is the full .gwt.xml I have now, where would I add it exactly?: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
 <source path="com/maillardcodes/portablefun" />
</module>

Comment: it does not matter where you add it as long as long it is inside <module></module>

Comment: Error:       Loading inherited module 'src.de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook.GdxFacebookCore'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'src/de/tomgrill/gdxfacebook/GdxFacebookCore.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
      [ERROR] Line 5: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)

Comment: can you also post the pom.xml?

Comment: There is no pom.xml, but I found an .iml file in the html project, attached above.

Comment: I am not sure what does this file does exactly. so you must be building the project with gradle ? or you are using to build tool at all ?

Comment: Yes, I'm building the project with gradle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118150/discussion-between-zakaria-amine-and-wonderfulworld).